# Angular and SVG: how to dynamically load custom components?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I need to dynamically load SVG items.

The items are very simple.
Template:

```
<svg:rect [attr.x]="x" [attr.y]="y" width="10" height="10" />
```

Class:

```
export class DraggableSvgItemComponent implements OnInit {

  x: number = 0;
  y: number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is how the container component template looks like:

```
<svg attr.height.px="{{height}}" attr.width.px="{{width}}">
    <svg:g app-draggable-svg-item *ngFor="let d of draggables" />
</svg>
```

And this is how I generate the items form the container component:

```
// commands <- load fun stuff with x and y coordinates
var toSet = new Array<DraggableSvgItemComponent>();
commands.forEach((value) => {
  if (value instanceof ZPL2.GraphicShapeBase) {
    var toAdd = new DraggableSvgItemComponent();
    toAdd.x = value.x;
    toAdd.y = value.y;

    console.log(toAdd);
    toSet.push(toAdd);
  }
});

this.draggables = toSet;
```

The console log shows that x and y have non zero values: `DraggableSvgItemComponent {x: 100, y: 50}` but the output is a svg with a square in the top-left corner and the values of x and y are 0.

If I put the `<rect>` directly in the canvas without using a different component it works but I need it because I have to deal with different svg stuff.

What am I doing wrong with the value bindings?

Comment: should I set an @input to the DraggableSvgItemComponent and pass to it the element of the list like described here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have to create the `DraggableSvgItemComponent` components in code. They will be created as children of the `<svg:g>` elements if you define the component selector as an attribute selector. The `x` and `y` properties could be marked with the [Input decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) to allow data binding.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[draggable-svg-item]',
  template: `<svg:rect [attr.x]="x" [attr.y]="y" width="10" height="10" />`
})
export class DraggableSvgItemComponent {
  @Input() x: number = 0;
  @Input() y: number = 0;
}
```

In the parent component, `draggables` can simply be an array of positions:

```
export class AppComponent {
  width = 200;
  height = 200;
  draggables = [
    { x: 5, y: 0 },
    { x: 20, y: 30 },
    { x: 0, y: 20 },
    { x: 24, y: 8 },
  ];
}
```

which are supplied to the child components with property binding:

```
<svg [attr.height.px]="height" [attr.width.px]="width">
    <svg:g draggable-svg-item [x]="d.x" [y]="d.y" *ngFor="let d of draggables" />
</svg>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8k7y9m) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Angular and I didn't know the existence of @Input yet!
I come from the MVVM world of WPF... So as you said draggable can be an array of my "models" while the "view" and "view-model" are created automatically by the *ngFor. Is the analogy correct?

Comment: The analogy is probably correct. I suggest reading [this page](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) of the Angular documentation. Several important concepts are well explained in it, including data binding. One special thing in your case is the use of an attribute selector for the child component. It avoids the wrapper component element that may cause trouble in the SVG syntax.

Comment: Is ```draggable-svg-item``` a component directive behave like an attribute directive? I don't see any documentation on [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) to do something like this, so potentially break in a future version of angular?

Comment: @wonderfulworld - Attribute selectors are allowed for `@Directive`, and `@Component` extends `@Directive`, according to [this Angular cheat sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet). So using that kind of selector for components should be safe.